Is the warp core solely a power source or is it also the mechanism that produces the warp field?
One of key bits of technology within Star Trek is the all important warp core. It is a matter-antimatter reaction chamber which produces the huge amounts of energy required to power the large ships in the shows (although other races use different power sources; I believe Romulans use artificial singularities).
Is the warp core just the source of the power required to achieve warp or is it also the mechanism that produces the warp field that allows faster-than-light travel? If it is just the source of the energy, then what bit of technology is it that actually produces the warp field? (I know that nacelles are involved.)

Yes, the warp coil is a power source.  But unlike an electric power plant, the warp core does not induce an electric current in a solid-state wire. Rather, the drive produces a highly-energized electro-plasma that flows via warp conduits directly to the warp coils. The warp-propulsion system is a lot like a gas stove! It directly utilizes an energized plasma to do work.

The Warp Core generates the power to create the warp bubble. Plasma created by the Warp Core is transferred to the Nacelles, where warp coils are energised by the plasma, the warp coils create the warp bubble.
So to answer your question directly, warp coils in the Nacelles generate the warp bubble, using plasma created in the Warp Core.

IOW, the Warp Core isn't a warp core, it's a power source.  Doesn't sound as cool, but that's all it is.

@RonJohn IIRC, there's other (backup) power sources which can power other parts of the ship (including impulse drive) without the warp core. However, the warp drive is dependent on the warp core functioning. So at least there's a reason for the name: warp is its raison d'etre.

@RonJohn Except it is a warp core. It’s the only power source on the ship that can provide enough power to sustain a warp field. If that wasn’t needed, they’d be just fine with the deuterium fusion generators that power the impulse drive, or whatever other power source they happened to have. We’re looking at multiple orders of magnitude of difference in available power (and to a lesser extent implied fuel efficiency) here, not just ‘yet another generator’.

@AustinHemmelgarn let's look at Real Life: power sources aren't named after the things they're used for, but how they generate power.  An example is supercarriers.  They don't have "propeller cores", they have nuclear generators.  Why are they called nuclear generators instead of "propeller cores"?  Because the energy is created using nuclear fission.

@RonJohn It's not just the power it provides via the warp plasma, it's implied that the warp plasma itself is part of how the warp bubble's formed. It's why the warp core isn't just a big M/AM collision engine (which wouldn't normally do anything but make gamma radiation), but requires mediation by dilithium crystals to generate the energized plasma. Contaminating the warp plasma sent the ship in "Little Green Men" back in time, and a failed plasma injector sent a runabout to the mirror universe in "Crossover", so it's probably doing something beyond just being a power source.

@Idran interesting.  The accepted answer and all the comments saying how wrong I am should have mentioned that.

@RonJohn I can't speak for the other commenters, but agreed for the answer, yeah. Binary Worrier, it might be worth editing to point out that the plasma generated by the warp core seems to play a role via more than just providing power to the warp coils?

@Idran, & RonJohn Please feel free to edit the the answer and add any missing details
